# Catching full string inside regex class

Tags: java, regex

I'm currently trying to deal with "leetspeak" in regex.  I have a class with a letter, and it will be filled with possible "leet" alternatives in it.  However, some of those alternatives are multiple characters long, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to include those in a class. For example

```
[kK"|<"]
```

Now I understand quotation marks don't work like that, but I can't find a way to have this match either k, K, or |< without it matching the | or < individually.

My questions is how can I include a string of characters within a class?

Also, I want to make sure it's treated literally, so I will need to include \Q and \E somewhere in the solution.

Comment: "*..how to include those in a class*" you can't, [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) is class of characters, not strings. You can try with something like `"k|K|\\|<"` instead. Also you can make your regex case-insensitive so you don't need to handle both `k` and `K` separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a class for both `k` and `K` then match `|<` by itself.

```
"[kK]|\\|<"
```

If you are wanting to include `\Q` and `\E` ...

```
"[kK]|\\Q|<\\E"
```

Comment: I don't think the `i` modifier is a good idea for him in general, because what works in [leet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet) uppercase will often not work in lowercase, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
"k|K|\\|<"
```

The pipe allows you to "or" a multicharacter string and escaping it with a backslash allows you to include a pipe in such a string.  You'll need to escape the backslash with another backslash if the string is in quotation marks, so the backslash can be placed as such in the Regex.

Comment: would "k|K|\\Q|<\\E" work as well? (I don't want to assume I know what the symbols may be)

Comment: seems so.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
[kK]|\|<
```

In Java, you need to escape the backslash, so this becomes

```
[kK]|\\|<
```

**Option 2: escape the leet**

As you suggested yourself, using `\\Q some leet \\E` lets you match anything without worrying that you may need to escape a special regex character.

**Explanation**

- The character class `[kK]` matches one char that is either a `k` or a `K`
- OR `|`
- `\|<` matches `|<`

Comment: Yes, you can escape any sequence with `\Q ... \E` (which becomes `\\Q .... \\E` in Java)